# Consulta con fecha en select

Tags: php, select

Tengo el siguiente  código que consiste básicamente en dos input se colocan dos fechas independientemente. Por otra parte, hay un select que funciona como filtro de búsqueda, debe buscar la entidad que se selecciona entre las dos fechas que ya fueron suministradas anteriormente. El problema es que al seleccionar por primera vez, sí las toma y muestra los resultados; sin embargo, al volver a utilizar el mismo select, al dar click en el botón y seleccionar la entidad, borra las fechas que se pusieron en un principio y pues no realiza la búsqueda.

Lo que deseo es que conserve las fechas cada vez que se pulsa el botón de búsqueda por entidad –

```html
<tr class="encabezadoT"> <td colspan=4>
               <form method="POST" onsubmit="return validar(this)">
                Desde: <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['dp2'])){echo $_POST['dp2'];}?>" autocomplete='off' readonly id="dp2" name="dp2"  style='width:120px' class="datepicker2" readonly  >
                
              Hasta: <input type="text"  readonly autocomplete='off' id="dp1" name="dp1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['dp1'])){ echo $_POST['dp1'];}?>"  style='width:120px'  class="datepicker2" >
              
             <input class="boton2" id="boton2" type="submit" value="Buscar por fecha" id="fecha" name="fecha" >
             </form>
           </td>
       <?php
       
       if(isset($_POST['fecha'])){
                $dp2=$_POST['dp2'];
                $dp1=$_POST['dp1'];
                
       }
       
    
   
 ?>
 
 
 
 
 
 
  <form method="POST">
                
               <select name=entidad id="entidad" > 
                   
                   <option disabled selected> Seleccione una entidad</option>
                   <option <?php if($entidad=="TODAS"){?>selected<?php }?>>TODAS</option>
                  <?php foreach($valor2 as $valor){//Mostrar en select la lista de los bancos
                     ?><option <?php if($entidad==$valor){?>selected<?php  }?>><?php  echo $valor; ?></option> <?php } ?>
                     
               </select>
               
                 <input class="boton2" type="submit" name="boton2" value="Buscar">
                   <input type=hidden name=dp1 value='<?php echo $dp1?>'>
                   <input type=hidden name=dp2 value='<?php echo $dp2?>'> 
             </form>

<?php 
$entidad='TODAS';
if(isset($_POST['boton2'])){  
$entidad = $_POST['entidad'];
$dp2=$_POST['dp2'];
$dp1=$_POST['dp1'];
echo $entidad;
}

?>
```

Comment: Solo se ve un select, dónde está el otro que suas? Organiza bien tu código que no se le entiende mucho

Comment: Podrias mirar [ask]? no se entiende nada de tu pregunta, podrias aclararla?

Comment: Apreta el boton [edit] y explica todo eso, con ejemplos, dibujos y todo lo que haga falta, en la pregunta. y lee el link que te pase.